# Increasing request size cause any issue?

Tags: c#

I have my request size to nearly to 2Mb.Will this cause any other issues?

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2048576" />
```

I am using many datasets and dictionaries saved in my view state.So I had to increase my request size.

Comment: The issue is that you are using many datasets and dictionaries saved in view state. (not the maxRequestLength itself) For each request user will send 2mb of data....it is a huge amount and your website will be very slow and unresponsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MaxRequestLength property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx) specifies the limit for the buffering threshold of the input stream. So one of the drawback I can think is that *this limit can be used to prevent denial of service attacks that are caused by users who post large files to the server.*

I would recommend only setting those larger values for the page that needs them rather than the site as a whole; both can be set programmatically for the page.

Comment: Thank you @Mohit for the reply.I will increase the size programmatically for the corresponding page.The issue is unexpected page load occurs when large data comes.It clears all View state values.Since I'm using many panels in the page as Wizard.When doing any operation it redirects to initial panel (Like initial page load)>I am fed up with this issue.Kindly give a solution, please.

Comment: Hey @Akhil you can add another question with more details of the issue you were facing. Since that would be easier to understand the scenario well.

Comment: I have added a question yesterday, but don't know what's wrong with it.Nobody gave a reply correctly.Since I'm new in C#  I am not sure my question is correct or not.Thank you @Mohit.Here

Comment: Here is the question : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262346/will-the-increased-view-state-size-cause-unexpected-errors).